# Concatenate multiple videos adding audio track with fade-out fade-in effects using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

The command to concatenate video using ffmpeg is like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.webm -i input3.mov \
-filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mkv
```

Command to add fade out/fade in effects at multiple points in audio would be like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "afade=enable='between(t,0,3)':t=in:st=0:d=3,afade=enable='between(t,7,10)':t=out:st=7:d=3,afade=enable='between(t,10,13)':t=in:st=10:d=3,afade=enable='between(t,13,16)':t=out:st=13:d=3" -t 16 output.mp3
```

I would like to combine those commands so that it would concatenate the video files and add audio track with fade in/fade outs between each video part. The problem is I can't see any option to get length of each input video so that I can use it to compute where to place the fade in/out effects. Any way to get those values while passing parameters to afade filter?

Comment: Use the [acrossfade filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#acrossfade). See duplicate links above for examples. I'm assuming you'll want to use `acrossfade=d=1.5:o=0` for each instance with afade at the beginning and end. For afade you will have to get duration for each input first. See [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe Tips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Formatcontainerduration).

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. I don't want a cross-fade effect. I just need to fade out/in the background audio at appropriate moments. I got to understand that I need to get the duration for each clip. @llogan , thank you, you are right. I was hoping to find another way, though.

Comment: acrossfade filter can be used to fade in/out between each input with optional crossfading. It has the advantage of not having to deal with input length. You would only need afade for the very beginning and very end. Is that not what you want to do?